# Formulas in script difficulty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am getting problems with an error message:

> Cannot find method to get formulasR1C1(String).

The line of script causing the problem is:

```
var trf1 = tr.getRange((trnew), , noofEntries, 1).setFormulasR1C1('Vlookup(Indirect(Address(Row(),Column()-2)),Funds,3,0)');
```

The formula `Vlookup(Indirect(.....)` works fine when applied to a specific cell manually. The script covers a range of 3 cells.

Comment: Please ensure the exact and full error text is in your question. Similarly, ensure that your question includes an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or the minimum context necessary to understand your issue. For example, what is `trnew`, why do you have an empty argument in the `getRange` call, etc.

Comment: @MarvynThomas You are using setFormulasR1C1 but your formula syntax is A1 Notation. You need to build the formula using R1C1 OR use setFormula or setFormulas (for A1 Notation).

Comment: I accept you suggestion and want to close this